# jquery some input add class keyup,keydown etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If type my input add border the li tags but just one where write the text.
This script is working, but how to short this jquery script?

Thanks help!

```js
.add_border{
 border: 2px solid #000 !important;
}
```

```css
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#input1').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste', function() {  
  if ($(this).val() == '') { $('#my_block1').removeClass('add_border'); } else {$('#my_block1').addClass('add_border'); }});
  
 $('#input2').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste', function() { 
  if ($(this).val() == '') { $('#my_block2').removeClass('add_border'); } else {$('#my_block2').addClass('add_border'); }});

});
```

```html
<ul>
 <li id="my_block1">  
  <span>some text 1</span>         
  <div class="form-group">
   <input id="input1" type="text" name="my_item_1">
  </div>
 </li>
 <li id="my_block2">  
  <span>some text 2</span>         
  <div class="form-group">
   <input id="input2" type="text" name="my_item_2">
  </div>
 </li>
 
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('#input1, #input2').on('input', function() { $('#my_block' + this.id.split('').pop()).toggleClass('add_border', this.value === ""); });`

Comment: @adeneo: Nice. But I think you need to negate this: ``this.value !== ""`` in order to achieve the same result as Drawer in the code above.

Comment: Thank You!
I try this:
$('#input1, #input2, #input3, #input4, #input5, #input6, #input7, #input8, #input9, #input10, #input11, #input12, #input13, #input14, #input15, #input16, #input17, #input18, #input19, #input20, #input21, #input22, #input23, #input24').on('input', function() { $('#block' + this.id.split('').pop()).toggleClass('add_border', this.value !== ""); });
9+ don't working. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `tag` to jQuery selector:

```
$('input').on('keyup keydown keypress change paste', function() {       
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('#my_block1').removeClass('add_border');
    } else {
        $('#my_block1').addClass('add_border'); 
    }
});
```

---

Answer to your last comment:

```
.on('input', function() {
```

There is no default `input` event. Read more in jQuery API about `on`:
http://api.jquery.com/on/
and about events here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/